# Best practice to separate OS environment docker image and application image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

this is my second day working with Docker, can you help me with a solution for this typical case:

Currently, our application is a combination of Java Netty server, Tomcat, python flask, MariaDB.

Now we want to use Docker to make the deployment more easily.

My first idea is to create 1 Docker Image for environment (CentOS + Java 8 + Python 3), another image for MariaDB, and 1 Image for application.

So the docker-compose.yml should be like this

```
version: '2'

services:
  centos7:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: centos7_env
    image:centos7_env
    container_name: centos7_env
    tty: true

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb/server:10.3
    container_name: mariadb10.3
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    tty: true

  app:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app_docker
    image: app:1.0
    container_name: app1.0
    depends_on:
      - centos7
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    volumes:
      - /home/app:/home/app
    tty: true
```

The app_dockerfile will be like this:

```
FROM centos7_env

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY docker_entrypoint.sh ./docker_entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker_entrypoint.sh"]
```

In the docker_entrypoint.sh there should couple of commands like:

```
#!/bin/bash

sh /home/app/server/Server.sh start
sh /home/app/web/Web.sh start
python /home/app/analyze/server.py
```

I have some questions:

1- Is this design good, any better idea for this?

2- Should we separate image for database like this? Or we could install database on OS image, then do commit?

3- If run docker-compose up, will docker create 2 containers for OS image and app image which based on OS image?, is there anyway to just create container for app (which run on Centos already)?

4- If the app dockerfile not base on OS image, but use FROM SCRATCH, so can it run as expected?

Sorry for long question, Thank you all in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to understand is that Docker container is not a VM - they are much more lightweight, so you can run many containers on a single machine.

What I usually do is run each service in its own container. This allows me to package only stuff related to that particular service and update each container individually when needed.

With your example I would run the following containers:

- MariaDB
- Container running `/home/app/server/Server.sh start`
- Container running `/home/app/web/Web.sh start`
- Python container running `python /home/app/analyze/server.py`

You don't really need to run `centos7` container - this is just a base image which you used to build another container on top of it. Though you would have to build it manually first, so that you can build other image from it - I guess this is what you are trying to achieve here, but it makes `docker-compose.yml` a bit confusing.

There's really no need to create a huge base container which contains everything. A better practice in my opinion is to use more specialized containers. For example in you case for Python you could have a container which container Python only, for Java - your preferred JDK.

My personal preference is Alpine-based images and you can find many official images based on it: `python:<version>-alpine`, `node:<verion>-alpine`, `openjdk:<version>-alpine` (though I'm not quite sure about all versions), `postgres:<version>-alpine` and etc.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have other questions and I will try to address them here.

Comment: Thank you very much, I rearranged like your advice with base image for env and web, server, analytic service, mariadb run in 4 different containers. All off them share same docker network and it seems going the correct path. I just confuse a little bit about two things: 1- should I copy the java or python server into containers or use volume for easier upgrade? 2- currently we use hazelcast , normally I just use <member>127.0.0.1</member> to make all nodes recognize each other but using containers, add <member>network</member> or even each service's name but not work, any experience for this?

Comment: Normally you would build your image from a base image which already has your runtime environment. I usually prefer Alpine-based images and you can find official images based on Alpine. For example: `python:<version>-alpine`, `openjdk:<version>-alpine`. If that is acceptable in your case, this is a good starting point.